# JMeter with Bcrypt replacement of SHA Hash

Tags: performance, hash, jmeter

I was using ${__groovy(org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils.sha256Hex('624111\0002021-10-06T11:35:39-04:00\000s3co3t\000'),)} to get the SHA 256 Hash key, now In place of SHA256, I have to use BCRYPT, Can anyone help here, How we use BCRYPT in JMeter OR Any JMeter Utill function defined for this

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in functionality to perform BCRYPT hashing in JMeter, you will need to use an external library like [JBCrypt](https://github.com/jeremyh/jBCrypt) or [Spring Security](https://reflectoring.io/spring-security-password-handling/)

1. Add the .jar of your choice with its [dependencies](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html) to [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
2. Restart JMeter to pick them up
3. You should be able to use the classes from .jars in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)